# My iPhone thinks it's 980px wide

Tags: css, iphone, width, media-queries, mobile-devices

I'm trying to create a set of three **very simple** media query's to handle a range of screen sizes. Here's what I came up with, after a bunch of headscratching:

```
@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px)  { styles here }  
@media all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1023px)   {  styles here } 
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {  styles here }
```

This works as I expected in browsers, but when I point my iphone at it, it insists on displaying the syles for the medium size.  Playing with the numbers, I found that **only with a max-width of 980px does the iphone respond to the styles within that query**.

Note that I used "all" on these queries to rule out anything to do with whether or not to code "handheld" or "screen, handheld" etc. Trying to simplify to help me understand the problem.

I thought it might have had something to do with the contents of the page I was developing, so I created a no-content test page to try to pin down the problem. It's at:

http://rgdaniel.com/test-mediaquery.php

If I look at that page with my desktop browsers, it behaves as expected when I resize the window larger and smaller. But the iPhone reports my "medium res" message at any specified max-width under 980px. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to combine min-width and max-width? I've only seen min-width increasing progressively being used.

Comment: Also see http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ if you're targeting mobiles specifically.

Comment: I first used only max-width on the first one, then min-width on the other two. It was still giving me problems as described, so I played around with the queries. This is just where I landed.

Comment: Yes, I did use those queries from stephen.io exactly as coded at one point, could not get things to behave...

Comment: Did you include this, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`? I don't see it in the link you have and if you did not, you need to include this in your `head` tag.

Comment: No problem, if it helps I'll add it as the answer. This allows the website to know it is being used on a device and not a desktop. First time with `media queries` for me lead to a lot of headaches until I found out I forgot a major part of them.

Comment: Hallelujah, that did the trick! THANK YOU!!

Comment: You are very welcome, I included an answer with a little bit of extra info. If the answer fixed your problem then please check it as the accepted answer. Best of luck!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When using `media queries` you *need* to add this to your `head` tag.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

This allows the website to detect that it is being used on a device.

You can also do this,

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">`

This part, `user-scalable=0;` prevents the user from zooming with their fingers and is useful if you have `position: fixed` elements.

Comment: No problem! I recommend you find a really nice tutorials on `media queries` and delve on in!

Comment: @LihO I am glad I could of been of some help. Best of luck in you're design!

Comment: I was banging my head against a wall until I found this. Thank you.

Comment: @BlakeFrederick No need to pound your head anymore than! Best of luck mate.

Comment: @JoshPowell  Chrome says `Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.`. You should loose the semicolon, or use a comma if you have an additional key-value pair hence this is the most up voted question.

Comment: @CESCO I'll looking into this and change it for now, thanks mate!