# Problems with media queries in genreal. No results

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I cannot seem to get any media queries to work. I have no idea why. I tried a million different things. It just wont work.

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
    #sidebar {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="side-footer">
    <p><a href="mailto:business@darmisdigitaldesigns.net?subject=Website">Contact Webmaster</a><br />&copy; DDD 2012-2014</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Meta Tag :**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Have you added the `meta-viewport` in head?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the output on a 'device' (ie. 'phone, tablet) ? If you're looking at it on a desktop/laptop 'max-device'width' won't work and for testing purposes replace it with 'max-width'...

Comment: Refer to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945658/my-iphone-thinks-its-980px-wide/19945844#19945844.

Comment: My viewport tag is as follows `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Can you try with just `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` and also hope you are using a device which has smaller resolution for testing this scenario?

Comment: Honestly have no idea what I did, but I got it working. Thanks for the help guys. I would answer the question but my lack of rep doesn't allow it.

Comment: Final note: I used Adobe Device Central for testing with `max-device-width` and it worked. Also got `max-width` working in the browser.

Comment: Okay great.. Answer it when you have enough rep.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/Tyvpx/)

max-width is the width of the target display area, e.g. the browser

max-device-width is the width of the device's entire rendering area, i.e. the actual device screen

the correct way to use this css rule in fiddle is

```
@media screen and  (max-width: 320px) {
    #sidebar {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```